# how to find Length of Last Word in the given string using java?

Tags: java

Given a string s consists of some words separated by spaces, return the length of the last word in the string. If the last word does not exist, return 0.
**

> 'I am getting wrong answer as output Your input "Hello World" Output 1
> Expected 5'

**
here is my solution
**`class Solution { public int lengthOfLastWord(String s) { if(s.length()==0) { return 0; } String words[]=null; words=s.split(""); String str=words[words.length-1]; return str.length(); } }`**

Comment: Should be: words=s.split(" "); with a space

Comment: yes " " should work

Comment: getting runtime exception error. Array index out of bound exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, here yo can get last word from string:

```
if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    String lastWord = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
    return lastWord.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `words=s.split(" ");` instead of `words=s.split("");`

Your delimiter should be a space.

Comment: i have done this. Although my answer is correct but getting runtime exception